# Template page not showing data in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-admin

I created a template page on WordPress Admin and just added a h2 heading which does not appear with associated link for the page but it's working if admin logged in wordpress login. I also made the page public on page setting but still the problem is not remove page data shown only to admin. I have searched many forums but didn't find any solution.

```
  <?php 
/*
 Template Name: Contact Us

*/

get_header(); ?>


<div class="contact-box1">
    <h2 >
  <br><br>
        YOUR ENQUIRY
   </h2>

 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

how to create template in WordPress?

```
     <?php
/**
 Template Name: Contact Us
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site may use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Amplified_Antennas
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header();
?>
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<div class="contact-box1">
    <h2>Contact ENQUIRY</h2>
</div>
<?php
endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>

<?php
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: i used the changes you provided but still i did't get the page data. but it's working while i logged in to wordpress. see the link please 

http://amplifiedantennas.com.au/contact-us-2/

Comment: please reset your permalink. check with other page slug name also.

Comment: i changed it to this http://amplifiedantennas.com.au/contact/  but still heading your enquiry not showing.

Comment: i updated the code it's working fine while i logged in to wordpress but did't work when i log it out. Can you please come on teamviewer to help out .

Comment: please note that every thing working fine if i logged in to wordpress but as i logged out i can't get the heading on page . it's may be minor issue with some user types . As i am new here so i can't get how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

its working fine in here its not problem with the templating i guess you have not selected the template name right side of the dashboard and only put one contact us to the page as http://amplifiedantennas.com.au/contact-us doesnt have anything assigned over there

Comment: i added the template . Did you get the heading Your enqury on the above link you mention?

Comment: no i didnt get the heading as u have not assigned the appropriate page template to the page http://amplifiedantennas.com.au/contact-us/ if u need help https://www.facebook.com/srexta

Comment: its working if i logged in to wordpress dashboard but not working if i logged out. as you can see on your browser you are not logged in to that wordpress admin so you did't get the heading.

Comment: have u made too many templates that say contact us still you have not signed that to the template http://amplifiedantennas.com.au/contact-us/

Comment: i assigned the template contact us to it.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED (I included the full code now):

It's not enough to include the header and the footer, you also need to include *the loop* in order to fetch the content which was for that particular page in the text editor (in the backend), where you should add/create your content.

So after creating that template, you need to create a "new page" in the backend, selecting that page template in the right sidebar.

In my example below, you would write your header into the title field in the backend, then it would be displayed as an `h2` in the real page. And the whole content (inluding that title `h2`) is wrapped in the `.contact-box1` DIV, as you had it in your original code.

example:

```
<?php 
/*
 * Template Name: Contact Us
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Amplified_Antennas
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div class="contact-box1">

<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
          <?php the_content(); ?>
    } // end while
} // end if
?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

P.S.:  In your posted code, you are not closing this DIV tag: `<div class="contact-box1">`

Comment: i added the code you mention above and in //Post content here i added the h2 heading but now i am getting HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Did you create a new page using that template in the backend?

Comment: http://amplifiedantennas.com.au/contact-us-2/ yes this is the page with that template  as you can see here is h2 heading in it but it did't apear in the page .